# Permutations in python (Hour,Minutes,Seconds)

Tags: python, permutation

Please, help.
I need to get list of all permutations, when first number from 0 to 23, second number from 0 to 59 and third number from 0 to 59.
For example:
01,01,01
...
10,10,10
...
23,59,59
...etc

Comment: We are not willing to do your homework. So, tell us your thoughts? What have you tried and where did you face problems?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: i tried this: key1 = list(permutations(range(0, 10), 6))
but in my situation numbers can repeat

Comment: Look into `itertools.product` instead - you don't actually want permutations, you want the cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if I have understood your question:

```
>>> [(h,m,s) for h in range(24) for m in range(60) for s in range(60)]
```